# Search bar with glyphicon inside (no borders)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3, can't get an icon / button on the right side without annoying borders. Could someone make me a demo, something similar?

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRt5D.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="search" name="Søk på siden" placeholder="Søk etter midtveisvurdering, IKO modellen eller hva du måtte ønske!" id="input" class="form-control" value="" required="required" title="Søk på siden">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-search">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: $lightgray;
  background-image: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $whiteblue;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-search {
  color: $silver;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.input-group-addon {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FAFBFD;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #FAFBFD;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $whiteblue;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[For the moment it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU8G9.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO... SO is not code giving machine but  people who wants to help when you get issue in your tried code. Come with code you have tried.

Comment: How to post code? This comment system...

Comment: Please edit your question and add css and also html in question for better understanding  your issue. Thank you

Comment: Added an image of how it looks like at the moment. I don't want the search icon to be seperated from the search bar, if you understood.

Comment: This is probably because you use a button

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you use a button. Try to output it like this :

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" name="Søk på siden" placeholder="Søk etter midtveisvurdering, IKO modellen eller hva du måtte ønske!" id="input" class="form-control" value="" required="required" title="Søk på siden">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

You'll possibly have to add

```
.glyphicon-search{
  float: right;
}
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Changed button position to "absolute" and made a padding. Wrapped all this in a new class. Anyway thanks for helping me out, but I've already got a solution :)